# confluent elasticsearch sink regex to assign to all topics and send to index

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have multiple topics in like this

```
client1-table1
client1-table2
client1-table3
client1-table4
```

I want my elasticsearch sink to listen for any incoming messages and send them to an index accordingly. However my current configurations are not working... what can I do... below is my elasticsearch sink

```
{
  "name": "es-data",
  "config": {
    "_comment": "-- standard converter stuff -- this can actually go in the worker config globally --",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",


    "_comment": "--- Elasticsearch-specific config ---",
    "_comment": "Elasticsearch server address",
    "connection.url": "http://127.0.0.1:9200",


    "_comment": "If the Kafka message doesn't have a key (as is the case with JDBC source)  you need to specify key.ignore=true. If you don't, you'll get an error from the Connect task: 'ConnectException: Key is used as document id and can not be null.",
    "key.ignore": "true"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please define _"my current configurations are not working"_. Do you get an error?

Comment: Well htey dont sink any data to any index.

Comment: In your Kafka Connect worker log, are there any `ERROR` messages?

Comment: I went to /var/log/kafka and there is nothing there.. no file to tail

Comment: ah I found it.. confluent log connect and confluent log kafka -f but nothing there that says anything

Comment: You should be using `confluent log connect -f`